# Binary/XML Serialization with encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, serialization, deserialization, aes

I need to serialize/deserialize an object with encryption. I am using the following code to serialize

```
private void mSerialize(Student objStudent)
    {           

        try
        {               

            byte[] key = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };                                                          
            byte[] iv = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
            string path = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName + "\\App_Data\\File.tq";

            Aes aes = Aes.Create();
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;                

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {                        
                    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(cs, objStudent);
                    //new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student)).Serialize(cs, objStudent);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);            
        }
        finally { }
    }
```

And the following is the code to deserialize:

```
 private void mDeserialize()
    {

        byte[] key = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
        byte[] iv = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

        string path = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName + "\\App_Data\\File.tq";
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;
        Student stuResult= null;            

        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    stuResult = (Student)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(cs);
                    //stuResult = (Student)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student)).Deserialize(cs);
                }

            }

            MessageBox.Show(stuResult.Name);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
```

I tried with both Binary and XML serialization/deserialization. I am able to serialize the object but when I deserialize it, I get the following error

**When using Binary method:** The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: CB-56-04-1E-BE-6E-7D-A1-26-B5-74-0D-6F-FA-D2-67-84 ...

**When using XML method:** There is an error in XML document (1, 1).

I tried doing the same thing with "DESCryptoServiceProvider" but it didn't work as well as I am getting the same errors.

Comment: `new BinaryFormatter()` => [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-7.0#remarks) : _"BinaryFormatter **is insecure and can't be made secure**. For more information, see the BinaryFormatter security guide."_ => [Security Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)

Comment: I would propably just zip the file with a password.

Comment: What OS platforms does this need to support? => Would [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=net-7.0) be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Regarding BinaryFormatter's safety concern, i tried the same code with XML serialization with no luck.

For OS platform, it will work on Windows 10 and onwards.

Comment: File.encrypt and File.decrypt needs the file to be created on the disk before encrypting it. I am looking to encrypt an object and then serialize it in order to avoid creation of a regular file on the disk.

Comment: Ah, I see. "On-the-fly" encryption, so to speak.

Comment: I just saw: In your **de**serialization code you have `CreateEncryptor()` but _I think_ you may actually need [CreateDecryptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.createdecryptor?view=net-7.0), there.

Comment: @Fildor, You are the man bro. sometimes you go through all the code and miss an obvious mistake. This was the problem. I changed it o "CreateDecryptor" and it worked like a charm. Many thanks man and have a blessed day :-)

Comment: Been there, done that. Fell for the same mistake. That's one of those you don't make twice.

Comment: The [Aes Classs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-7.0) documentation has examples.

Comment: flagging to close because of typo